# How to manufacture Inrunner BLDC motor core

Tags: motors, electromagnetism, construction-management

I need to make a 10 slot BLDC inrunner motor core that is 40mm wide has 10mm inner diameter and 10mm thick. How would I make this? I would want to make it out of mild steel but I do not have a CNC machine and only a 3d printer. If anyone knows how a company that can CNC for me then send me parts, that would also be great(Bit like JLC PCB 3d printing service) as I think CNC is probably best route for this. Ideally I would like 8 of these cores.

[image]

Comment: If it's $40, lots of time, and a 3d printer, spend the 40 on some fasteners.  Wrapping wire around screws or nails, and a 3d printed case?

Comment: You can buy a hex or square shaft for the rotor.  As long as your epoxy keeps the magnets on, and the shaft works alright in the bearings, you should be fine.  You can cover the small amount of machining you need with a rotary tool with ceramic cutoff disks (like a Dremel), and cobalt drill bits (and a drill).

Comment: You limit the solutions to what you suggest. 3D printer and $40...

Comment: Hmmm... I will get rid of the $40 budget if that is the case.

Comment: @Abel I also thought about 3d printing the case. The screws are a neat idea, however, I am pretty sure they do not demagnetise quickly, and retain a lot of residual magnetism, so it wouldn't be very efficient...

Comment: You have already answered your question by limiting to cnc now. You are better off hopping on google maps and searching for a machine shop than asking here on the stack. I do not believe Mike meant "throw away your constraints" since real constraints persist regardless of whether you ignore them.

Comment: @Abel There are companies that CNC electrical/mild steel??? Do you know any that I can use...

Also, I realised that mild steel has a relative permeability of 2000, so your screw design could work, only problem is finding a mild steel crew of the necessary dimensions. I think a hex nut would be better geometrically than a screw for this. Most of them are stainless steel though, do you know where I could find mild steel ones?

Thanks. I'm probably going to delete this question after since you solved the manufacturing for me =)

Comment: Any machine shop worth their mill can work mild steel. Check mcmaster for what's available, and then search elsewhere for lower prices. There are extremely small screws available - electronics such as watches and phones use sub-mm screws (those tend to be stainless, but slightly above 1 mm should exist).  If you want to go even cheaper, paperclips might work; they are weak though.

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot for your help.  I do not need anything as small as sub-mm so I'll probably just try and find a mild steel hex head instead of the hassle of a machine shop.